# I can not return JSON variable from jquery ajax function

Tags: javascript, json, jquery, global-variables, response

I have function:

```
    function get_playlist(){    

        var result = jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'getrandommp3',
                nonce:'<?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'randmp3' ); ?>'
            },
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response); // All OK!
                window.response = response;
                var customvar = response;
                return response;
            }               
        });
        console.log(window.response); // undefined
        console.log(result.responseText); //undefined
        console.log(customvar); //undefined
        return window.response; // returning undefined
    }
```

I need to return json variable from function. Inside `success: function(response) {` responce have needed content. But outside of `Jquery.ajax` i have problems...

This code needed for jquery mp3 player...

```
var playlist = get_playlist(); 
var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options); 
myPlaylist.shuffle(true, true);
```

Thank you for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the way AJAX works (asynchronously). The `console.log` statements outside of the `success` event handler are executed before the response has been returned (so nothing has been assigned to `window.response` yet). Put the code that relies on the AJAX response inside the `success` event handler.

Alternatively, you could make the request synchronous, but that's usually not what you want as it can lock the browser until the response is returned.

**Update** (see comments and edit to question)

As I mentioned previously, you need to put all code that relies on the AJAX response inside the ready event handler:

```
function get_playlist(){    
    var result = jQuery.ajax({
        //Other AJAX options removed
        success: function(response) {
            var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, response, options); 
            myPlaylist.shuffle(true, true);
        }               
    });
}
```

Comment: I have Jquery player and i need return json mp3's list for it. `var playlist = get_playlist();

   var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist(cssSelector, playlist, options);
   myPlaylist.shuffle(true, true);`

Comment: Then create the `jPlayer` inside the `success` event handler. See my edit.